# Why does my img element have so much space around it?

Tags: html, css, image

Why is there so much spacing around my logo? I set the padding and margins to 0 on the ul, I cant think of other reasons.

[Heres a codepen.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/wMLMzZ)

### HTML

```
<div id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li class="logo"><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/opmt95.png"/></li>
    <li>File</li>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>Help</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#menubar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#menubar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menubar ul {
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#menubar ul .logo img {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a lot of space to me.  The text is right up against the orange PNG.

Comment: Sorry by whitespace I meant orangespace haha. Updated question

Comment: Also your code above doesn't match the Codepen

Comment: The black portions of the image are surrounded by large amounts of transparent areas of the image. I'd suggest you fire up your favourite image editor and clip the image.

Comment: @stack_pooper If the problem is the orange area, then just remove transparent pixels. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is the orange area, it is because your image have transparent pixels:

[image]

Open image editor, remove transparent pixels and the orange area will be as small as you want.